# Only Ipad-Exception saying Movie player has wrong activation state

Tags: ios, iphone

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'movie player <MPMoviePlayerControllerNew: 0x7ce3d230> has wrong activation state (1)'
*** First throw call stack:
(

4   MediaPlayer                         0x01968ef3 - [MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _moviePlayerDidBecomeActiveNotification:] + 239

5   Foundation                          0x03055c49 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke + 40

6   CoreFoundation                      0x03bef4a4 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20

7   CoreFoundation                      0x03add03b _CFXNotificationPost + 3051

8   Foundation                          0x03045246 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 98

tNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 98
9   MediaPlayer                         0x0196bd96 -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 133
10  MediaPlayer                         0x0196bd01 -        [MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _postNotificationName:object:] + 68
```

I dont know why this issue is occurring only in Ipad and not in iphone?
Any one if they could help..what should i do to remove this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able solve this problem by using below mentioned code in method that call every time user request to play the song

```
if ([MoviePlayer isPreparedToPlay]) {
            [MoviePlayer stop];
        }
```